# Entity Framework Select: Can I specify columns from dictionary?

Tags: asp.net, select, frameworks, entity

I'm wondering if there's an easy method to do this.  I can't really write a saple, because it doesn't exist in my work, yet.

```
 public ActionResult GetMyData(ICollection<string> MyColumns);
```

that I can call like so:

```
ICollection<string> MyCols = new List<string>();
MyCols.Add("Column1");
MyCols.Add("Column2");
GetMyData(MyCols);
```

Where my GetMyData queries a collection from my database, selecting the columns given in MyCols.  Consider this Collection called MyData:

```
MyData.Select(s => new { s.Columns1, s.Column2 }
```

I know my syntax is way off there, but I'm not able to correct at the moment.

Does such a method exist?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this? What's the context? I've done something like this for exporting to CSV, but taking in an IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T,String>>>. I can't see the appeal of creating an IEnumerable of anonymous type though? You can use Reflection to identify class members by name, but the big question remains what are you trying to do and why, because there is probably a better option.\

Comment: From my controller, I'm calling a method that reads parameters from the query string to piece together a collection of entities.  Some of these entities are persistent, but some are not.  Now, for some of my jQuery controls, I only need 1 or 2 properties of the entities in this collection.  I'd like to be able to specify via query string (or post variables) a string that's a comma delimited string of property names, and have those projected onto the set, and have that returned via JsonResult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These might help in that they indicate the principle - you could make a similar one using your JSON parser of choice instead of aggregating to CSV - JSON is just a formatted string after all.

You'd be replacing the Aggregate part, with something that built JSON. In mine, the aggregate is comma-separating the property values, you'd obviously have a different thing there.

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function ToCSV(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), dataFields As IEnumerable(Of Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, String)))) As String()
    Dim compiledFields As IEnumerable(Of Func(Of T, String)) = dataFields.Select(Function(e) e.Compile)
    Return source.
        Select(Function(x) compiledFields.Select(Function(d) d.Invoke(x)).
                   Aggregate(Function(seed, value) seed & ", " & value)).ToArray
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function ToCSV(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), dataFields As IEnumerable(Of String)) As String()
    Dim fields = GetType(T).GetProperties().Where(Function(p) dataFields.Any(Function(f) f = p.Name))
    Return source.Select(Function(x) fields.Select(Function(f) f.GetValue(x, Nothing).ToString).
                             Aggregate(Function(seed, value) seed & ", " & value)).ToArray
End Function
```

Edit - should probably point out that there is a really high chance of failure, because if you are letting users specify names of properties they will get them wrong and they won't be found - you also potentially open up security problems if your tables contain sensitive fields, unless you add a security layer of some sort to filter out those property names